# How to get windows form information on to a web applicatioin

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, webforms, smartsheet-api

I realise there is more than one way to skin a cat but I am wanting some opinions on a good approach to the next step in my program. I have created a windows form that firstly downloads a summary of weekly data from smartsheets and then puts it into an SQL database. Secondly, the user is able to select a number of graphs from a dropdown box and these are displayed on the web form and the data is from the SQL database. I have obviously coded all this in C#. I wanted to do this as a proof of concept that I could do it because I am still fairly new to C#. But have subsequently thought it would be beneficial to get this on the web, but realise that windows forms are not the way to go about it.

I am hoping someone can explain to me what would be a good approach to rectify this situation. Can I use the same code that I used to access smartsheets/database and create graphs in a web forms application? Or is this not able to be done on webforms?

Open to any ideas on this I just need to know which direction to head so I don't go off on a tangent.

Comment: Just an FYI, the smartsheet C# sdk can be used on any platform that can run C#. So that code will be very similar.

Comment: @Danrex, You might also be interested in [smartsheetlabs.com](https://smartsheetlabs.com/). The site has a charts app that will let you create graphs/charts from data on a sheet.

Answer (score 2):

[Us a Three-Tier Architecture Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) this basiclly splits up the application in 3 tiers, presentation ( asp.net , winforms , wpf ), business and data layer ( class libraries ). If designed correctly, your're able to switch the presentation layer for the other.